# Can I add assigns to the “main socket” after the connection is already established?

Tags: websocket, elixir, phoenix-framework

As explained by [this post](https://elixirforum.com/t/socket-assign-is-empty-in-handle-in/2018/4?u=szjx), when the client first connects with the server, a “main socket/process” gets created and holds its assigns. Later, when the client joins specific channels/topics, each channel’s socket/process copies those assigns and can add to them as it will.

I now have a use case where, upon the user joining their own individual channel `(i.e. user:#{user_id})`, I retrieve some information about the user from the DB, which should then be globally available to all channels this user later joins. However I haven’t been able to find a way to put those information into `socket.assigns` so that they can be available everywhere. If I try to assign them, they will only be available in the `socket.assigns` of this particular `user:#{user_id}` channel.

Is there a way to do it? Should I just instead simply try to fetch all those information in one go when the user first connects, instead of when they join the individual user channel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different channels mean different sockets.

The easiest solution would be to maintain the permanent state (`Agent`, `ETS`, `DETS`, `mnesia`, ...), holding a map `user_id => user_info` and query this state whenever you need this info.